# Make popup close when user clicks outside of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a user clicks on a div, a popup appears.  When they click anywhere outside of the popup, the popup should close.  Right now, the popup only closes when the user clicks outside of the div.  If the user clicks the div when the popup is on the screen, then the popup doesn't go away.  I think this is because the div itself has an on click event that causes the popup to appear, so clicking on the div doesn't actually make it go away.

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $('.popup').show();
});

// Clicking the 'x' hides the pop up
  $('.fa-times').click(function () {
  $('.popup').hide();
  });

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $(".popup");

  var clickedElement = e.target;

  if (!container.is(clickedElement) || clickedElement.className === 'box') {
    container.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.popup {
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

.popup .fa-times {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 2%;
}

.popup .fa-times:hover {
  color: #D54444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css"
                integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
                crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="box">
  <div class="popup">
  <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddler56/6xvLzo1y/)

The way I tried to fix this is by getting the class name of the clicked element and if this element is the div, then hide it.  But this did not work.  I'm assuming this is because clicking it causes the pop up to appear.

I have looked at many similar questions on stackoverflow but they did not help.  Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, something like this?

```
$('.box').click(function() {
  $('.popup').toggle()
})

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if (e.target.className != 'box')
    $('.popup').hide()
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2bg9e3f6/1/